# VBA: Nested Loops: sum columns within dataset

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to sum the values within columns, which are separated by blocks, within a dataset. The loops seem to be iterating correctly but the values within the loop “a” that output within the immediate window are not what I expected; it seems to be referencing 1 cell in column A, 5x. The script contains comments describing what I’m trying to achieve.

```
Sub sumCells()

Dim i, r, a, numObs As Integer
Dim Fa, Fb, Fc, Fd, Fe As Long

numObs = 10

Dim subStart As Integer

'loop to separate data into "blocks" of 10 rows (numObs). Step function used
'to contain loops below within each block. starts at 2 due to headers
For subStart = 2 To sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count Step numObs

   'loop to reference the rows within the subStart loop block
    For r = 2 To numObs

      'Loop to reference columns 1 through 5 (ideally I'd like to be able to
       'have this reference the actual column index so i dont have to
       'include more lines above to arrange the data accordingly
        For a = 1 To 5

           'this section is supposed to sum the values within each column
           'in this case, columns 1 to 5, within the rows specified above
           Fa = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(r, 1))
           Fb = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(r, 2))
           Fc = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(r, 3))
           Fd = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(r, 4))
           Fe = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(r, 5))

       Next a

  Next r

Next subStart

End Sub
```

sample of the data, data starts on row 2, headers not included:

```
    0   4   6   8   10  762 857 997
  643   6   9   12  15  739 775 1084
  784   8   12  16  20  938 828 968
 1235   10  15  20  25  832 827 751
  809   12  18  24  30  759 131 1085
 1373   14  21  28  35  589 102 900
 1300   16  24  32  40  656 798 962
  901   18  27  36  45  782 812 786
  761   20  30  40  50  706 951 741
```

Comment: Matt can you show us your sheet data please? a sample would do..

Comment: in your last for loop you never use the value for A For a = 1 To 5

Fa = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(a, 1))

Comment: It doesn't have loop reference to `r` either...if think of `a`'s point of view..

Comment: Hi Matt - `Fa = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(r, 1))` is only summing 1 cell. You need to either specify the range of cells that you want to add together - in which case you don't need to loop through the rows - do `Fa = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Cells(2,1), Cells(numObs,1))`, or add them together using your existing loop `Fa = Fa + Cells(r, 1).Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to sum each block of ten in each column and print that to the immediate window this code should work:

```
Sub sumcols()

Dim blocks As Integer
Dim Fa As Long, Fb As Long, Fc As Long, Fd As Long, Fe As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

blocks = 9

For i = 2 To Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row Step blocks + 1 'A1048576' will need to be changed if excel version older than '07
    'get sums for columns a through e for block starting with row i

    Fa = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("sheet1").Range("A" & i & ":A" & i + blocks))
    Fb = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("sheet1").Range("B" & i & ":B" & i + blocks))
    Fc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & i & ":C" & i + blocks))
    Fd = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("sheet1").Range("D" & i & ":D" & i + blocks))
    Fe = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheets("sheet1").Range("E" & i & ":E" & i + blocks))

    'print values to immediate window
    Debug.Print Fa
    Debug.Print Fb
    Debug.Print Fc
    Debug.Print Fd
    Debug.Print Fe

Next i

End Sub
```

Edit:

to make the columns iterate as well use:

(Fa will return the sum for every column in this case)

```
Sub sumcols()

Dim blocks As Integer
Dim Fa As Long, Fb As Long, Fc As Long, Fd As Long, Fe As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim currange As Range

blocks = 9

For i = 2 To Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row Step blocks + 1 'A1048576' will need to be changed if excel version older than '07
    'get sums for columns a through e for block starting with row i

    For j = 1 To 5 'iterate through columns

    'get range to sum (first range will be A2:A12)
    Set currange = Sheets("sheet1").Range(Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i, j), Sheets("sheet1").Cells(i + blocks, j))

    Fa = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(currange) 'Fa will return the sum for each column for each block

    'print values to immediate window
    Debug.Print Fa

    Next j

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Scott, this seems to be doing the trick. However, its adding 11 rows instead of 10, which I think I should be able to figure out. Thanks so much, I seem to have been over-complicating the solution in my original post